# recently upgraded to xCode 7.1. tableView doesn't display correctly

Tags: xcode, tableview, upgrade

recently upgraded to xCode 7.1. Now when i run my app in the simulator the tableview lines don't display unless i touch the cells. Anyone else experiencing this?

Comment: I have observed this but never faced any issue with this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

No data was on my app. I tested out some more and it worked.